# Catching failed OmniAuth login attempt information in Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

Goal: I'm trying to get a Ruby on Rails application to send me emails whenever a user fails to log into OmniAuth. I want the e-mail to include (1) the username entered in the form, and (2) an MD5 hash of the password field.

Obstacle: OmniAuth returns a POST after a successful login, and a GET after an authentication failure. The "success" POST includes the username and a filtered password, but the "fail" GET does not include these two parameters.

So I guess my question is "Can I make OmniAuth return the parameters I want? If not, how can I make Rails remember the form data *after* it gets POST'ed to OmniAuth?"

Comment: Are you using omniauth on its own for authentication or combining it with another engine like Devise / authlogic?

Comment: I think we're using OmniAuth by itself. I do not see any gems in the Gemfile or "External Libraries" that correspond to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the OmniAuth team and they gave me the solution below (thank you so much!):

> You can do custom failure handling by adding an on_failure action.
>
> OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new { |env| #do stuff }
>
> https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb
> is the default failure endpoint as an example

So I added the following in config/initializers/omniauth.rb:

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new{|env|
myLog = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new("log/omniauth_log.txt"))
myLog.tagged("OmniAuth", "ENV") { myLog.info "Failed login attempt - username: #{env["rack.request.form_hash"]["username"]}, password: #{env["rack.request.form_hash"]["password"]} "}
OmniAuth::FailureEndpoint.new(env).redirect_to_failure}
```

...and it records the username and password correctly. All that's left to do is encrypt the password.

If you want to display everything that's going on, you can log #{env.inspect} itself. It's a very large hash though (that also contains smaller hashes), so maybe log #{env.inspect} once and pick out the fields relevant to your task.